# Issue with finding string in text file using java

Tags: java, file-io, awt

I am working on a very basic sentiment analysis program which divides the sentence into an array of words and search each word in three files (positive, negative, and neutral) based on number of words with each sentiment, I want to display average score. I want to rate the sentence on a scale of 1-10 (with 10 being happy and 0 being sad). I have initialized the score with 5 which is a neutral score.

When I run the program, the result only displays 5 as score. Looks like there is some issue with finding the string in the file.

```
    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String str = t1.getText();
            Label result;
            int score = 5;
            String[] words = str.split("\\s+");

            for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {                    
                words[i] = words[i].replaceAll("[^\\w]", "");
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){

                if(search_pos(words[i])){
                    score = (score + 10)/2;
                    break;
                }

                if(search_neg(words[i])){
                    score = (score + 5)/2;
                    break;
                }

                if(search_neu(words[i])){
                    score = (score - 10)/2;
                    break;
                }
            }


            result=new Label("score is " + score);
            result.setBounds(50,350, 200,30); 

            f.add(result);


        }

    });



static boolean search_pos(String s){

    Scanner scanner=new Scanner("F:\\pos-words.txt");

    boolean flag = false;

    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
        if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(scanner.nextLine().trim())){
            // found
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}

static boolean search_neg(String s){

    Scanner scanner=new Scanner("F:\\neg-words.txt");

    boolean flag = false;

    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
        if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(scanner.nextLine().trim())){
            // found
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}

    static boolean search_neu(String s){

    Scanner scanner=new Scanner("F:\\neu-words.txt");

    boolean flag = false;

    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
        if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(scanner.nextLine().trim())){
            // found
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}

}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example purpose on your issue, I am providing the sentimental mix within single file, you don't have to match the words with neutral, positive and negative are enough, but if you want that, you can count those neutral words, okay let's go the the example.

First the score containing file is `words_score.txt`:

```
good    8
best    10
awesome 9
right   5
correct 7
outstanding 9
bad -8
worst   -10
flop    -7
wrong   -6
disgusting  -9
sucks   -8
```

then with assumption class:

```
package swing_practice;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestClass {

    private static final File scoreFile = new File("/home/arif/workspace/swing_practice/src/swing_practice/words_score.txt");

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        try{
            String str = purifySentence("I think what did that fellow does, is good for her but If I speak from that girl side, it's worst kind of thing.");
            int score = 5;
            String[] words = str.split("\\s+");

            for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                //System.out.println("Score for the word is : " + words[i] + " - " + getScore(words[i]));
                score += getScore(words[i]);
            }

            //if you want with 3 files, just write three methods like getScore and append the score variable similarly as above

            if(score < 0)
                score = 0;
            if(score > 10)
                score = 10;

            System.out.println("Score of the sentence is : " + score);

        }catch(FileNotFoundException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static String purifySentence(final String sentence){
        String purifiedValue = "";

        if(sentence.length() == 0){
            return "";
        }else{
            for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++){
                char ch = sentence.charAt(i);
                if(Character.isAlphabetic(ch) || ch == ' ')
                    purifiedValue += String.valueOf(ch);
            }
        }
        return purifiedValue;
    }

    private static int getScore(final String word) throws FileNotFoundException{
        int score = 0;
        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(scoreFile);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            final String line = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] wordNScore = line.split("\t", -1);
               if(wordNScore[0].equalsIgnoreCase(word)) {
                   score = Integer.parseInt(wordNScore[1]);
                   scanner.close();
                   break;
               }
        }
        return score;
    }

}
```

and the output is as below said:

```
Score of the sentence is : 3
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, i just made a change in the code that is the file path. I made it "F:\\words_score.txt" and the output is again 5. No matter what I type, the answer is always 5. I am running the project in NETBEANS. What could be the issue?

Comment: bro, writing honestly, i didn't watched your code, but on first testing I also get the result 0 in the testing part, I think it was just because of the getScore method result simple putted to the score = getScore(word) and thus corrected it to score += getScore(word), so I founded that I can write the code just in time, so that I did, and one more request to you, just click on the one number so it will become the answer for you and helpful also for others.